# How can you demonstrate scalabity and load balancing property of a cloud application on Windows Azure?

Tags: project-management, cloud-computing, azure

For my project I want to develop an web application with Windows Azure as the platform using C# language. The idea is to host the website of a University on the cloud. Whenever it announces the resutls online there is a spike and the cloud will handle the peak usage with its scalabilty and load balancing properties and deploy necessary resources.

However since all of this is handled by Azure internally there is no way of demonstrating it in our project. Is there a way where we can specifically implement something to demonstrate it to the evaluator?

A virtual way perhaps...

Answer (score 2):

you can use performance tools that generate requests to the server and measure the response time, server resources etc.
I've used HP's performance center & VUGen in the past, and it worked well for me.